# New Nav bounty layout error with many tabs

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, new-nav

When I add many new tabs, the left side of the tab bar, with the new tab button, looks like this:

[image: bounties wraps]

#### Browser:

Safari 8.0.7 (10600.7.12)

Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.4

<sup><sup>User Agent String: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_4) AppleWebKit/600.7.12 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0.7 Safari/600.7.12</sup></sup>

Comment: which browser are you using?

Comment: @m0sa See edit.

Comment: I see the bug. Will fix soon.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers Great!

Comment: @JF can you confirm that this has been resolved in the latest build? It was a flex-box safari bug.

Comment: @Kurtis It’s fixed.